# Using Omnifaces EL functions in composite component with Mojarra 2.2.5

Tags: composite-component, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

After upgrading to JSF Mojarra 2.2.5, i get the following exception when using Omnifaces's el function formatNumber. This only occurs within a composite component. Normal Facelet is working fine.

javax.el.ELException: Function 'of:formatNumber' not found

this is my composite component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="cart" required="true" type="org.ead.eeb.order.ShoppingCart" />
        <cc:attribute name="allowCouponRemove" required="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
        <cc:attribute name="removeCouponBean" type="java.lang.Object" />
        <cc:attribute name="removeCouponAction" type="java.lang.String" />
        <cc:attribute name="removeCouponProperty" type="java.lang.String" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <h4>Übersicht</h4>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.cart.items}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><abbr title="#{item.description}">#{item.name}</abbr></td>
                        <td class="text-right">#{of:formatNumber(item.totalAmount, '#0.00')}  €</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mehrwertsteuer (#{cc.attrs.cart.taxRatePercentage} %)</td>
                    <td class="text-right">#{of:formatNumber(cc.attrs.cart.totalTax, '#0.00')} €</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="active">
                    <td><strong>Gesamtbetrag</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-right"><strong>#{of:formatNumber(cc.attrs.cart.totalOrderAmount, '#0.00')} €</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        ...
    </cc:implementation>
```

thanks in advance for your help :)

**Edit:**
the problem occurs, if i use the value from `cc.attrs.*`. If I use the value directly as an attribute, everthing is working well. Any ideas?

**Edit2:**
A workaround is possible by the following code

```
<c:set var="test" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
#{of:formatNumber(test, '#0.00')}
```

but that's pretty ugly. I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Reminds me of an old Mojarra bug. What happens if you put `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"` inside `<cc:implementation>`?

Comment: Yeah right, I've found the old threads about this. But putting the namespace declaration in the implementation tag makes no difference.

Comment: Weird. Let me try it on 2.2.5 ...

Comment: Well, works for me. Which OmniFaces version and which container make/version? What was the old Mojarra version on which this worked previously for you?

Comment: I am running Omnifaces 1.7 on Glassfish 4 (build 89). Previously I used Mojarra 2.2.4, which was fine.

Comment: hm thats weird, i just tested it with a minimal example and it's working as well. So I have to figure out what's the problem in my real world application.

Comment: update: the problem occurs, if i use the value from `cc.attrs.*`. If I use the value directly as an attribute, everthing is working well. But I can't find any solution for that. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here with same setup.

Comment: Even more interesting this even happens if within a filter a redirect was issued to a different site (which is not using any functions and displays correct).

Comment: I have the same problem with #{p:component(...)} inside composite component. It isn't omnifaces specific problem.

Comment: The problem is in missing namespaces in NamespaceHandler instance

Comment: Created an issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3469

Answer (score 1):

The issue i created was marked as Wont't Fix, since there is a workaround:

Replacing all convenient inline el calls of type `#{foo}` with `<h:outputText value="#{foo}"/>`.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3469

*Very inconvenient and cumbersome. Many regressions from 2.2.4 -> 2.2.5.*