# EL expression for label not resolved

Tags: primefaces, el

This is a follow up for my [FindComponent + set invalid challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558997/findcomponent-set-invalid-challenge) question...

In that question it all worked fine for static strings, like:

```xml
<p:inputText id="val2" readonly="true" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val2}" label="label2">
    <f:attribute name="someAttribute" value="value2" />
</p:inputText>
```

...but when I changed to EL it is "not working":

```xml
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <p:outputLabel value="Val 2: #{cc.attrs.data.label2}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <p:inputText id="val2" readonly="true" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val2}" label="#{'l2'.concat(cc.attrs.data.label2)}">
            <f:attribute name="someAttribute" value="#{'a2'.concat(cc.attrs.data.label2)}" />
        </p:inputText>

    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

I know that `#{cc.attrs.data.label2}` is not empty, "printing" on `p:outputLabel` works.

**edit 1:**

I found this question - [Using Omnifaces EL functions in composite component with Mojarra 2.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384920/using-omnifaces-el-functions-in-composite-component-with-mojarra-2-2-5) but I do not know whether it is related or not. My versions are

```
Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14
Running on PrimeFaces 6.2
Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2.4
Using OmniFaces version 1.14
```

Comment: You are using outdated versions of ALL of the above libraries so I would not doubt if its fixed in later versions of either OmniFaces, Mojarra, PF, or a combination of all 3.